# 'Provider' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I've recently updated my react-router-dom to v6. The new version is very strict about the types used. When I use a redux provider in my code I get the following error message:

```
TS2786: 'Provider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
```

But it is fine for other providers:

```
root.render(
  <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebase}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<div>hello</div>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </FirebaseAppProvider>,
);
```

Do you have any solution rather than `ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 16):

This seems to occur recently when you have multiple versions of `@types/react` installed through dependencies.

Some workarounds can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1094565891

Comment: I ran `yarn upgrade` to get my `@types/react` on the latest version and that fixed this for me

Comment: Had the problem that I had it globally and locally (in a project) installed. Removing the global available node modules did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue of React 18.
Can add
{/*
// @ts-ignore */}  to ignore it.
But not recommended