# Its instance type 'Provider<AnyAction>' is not a valid JSX element. The types returned by render()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

[image]Provider error suddenly, yesterday was fine, how to solve this problem ?

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: where do you import `Provider` from?

Comment: import { Provider } from "react-redux";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877218/provider-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component

Answer (score 2):

According to this post by [phry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2075944/phry) it can be caused by having multiple versions of `@types/react` installed on you project, check your `package.json` and see the recommendations on the post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71877791/6854709